# The peculiar inequality

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-theory

Let's have the following relation

$\sqrt[3]{\frac{(x+1)^3+x^3}{2}}\lessgtr\frac{2x^2+2x+1}{2x+1}$

where $x$ a  positive integer greater than zero. Which inequality is valid?

Comment: If we make the following subtraction $(2x^2+2x+1)^3-[(\frac{(2x+1)^3+x^3}{2}\times(2x+1)^3]=\frac{3x^2+3x+1}{2}$. Verbally we can say, the side of the half of the sum of two cubes is almost equal to $\frac{R^2+1}{2R}$. For $x=9$ we have $S=\frac{19^2+1}{2\times19}=9.526315$ and $\sqrt[3]{\frac{1729}{2}}=9.526243$. $R$ means radius of a circle. $R=2x+1$.

Comment: It's hard to see the relation between the subtraction you mentioned in the first sentence and the claim in the next sentence. Can you elaborate more? I feel like you're trying to fish out an elegant substitution that will make solving this easy, but I'm not getting the hints you gave so far. If anything, the subtraction you mentioned is not that easy.

Comment: The result has been obtained as follow. First we raise both sides of the inequality to the third power. Then we eliminate the denominator of the term on the right by multiplying both sides by $(2x+1)^3$.  After performing the calculations, we obtain the result shown above. This inequality derives from complex mathematics.

Comment: Um, that's what I did in my answer. So you mean the sum of the two cubes in your comment should be $(x+1)^3+x^3$ instead of the current one $(2x+1)^3+x^3$, right?

Comment: You're right.  Thanks for catching my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Cube both sides, simplify, to get:
$$-3x^2-3x-1 \lessgtr 0$$

Since $3x^2+3x+1>0$, therefore:
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{(x+1)^3+x^3}{2}}\lt\frac{2x^2+2x+1}{2x+1}$$

---

Or, a cheeky way to solve this: assuming exactly one of greater than or less than is true, plug in $x=1$ to see that the left side is smaller than the right side.

Comment: Your answer is missing something.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis and what would that be? Remember, there are other ways to solve the problem, besides your intended solution.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis, so, any hint on what's missing from this answer?

Comment: @justhalf In my comments above I have shown that the difference is $\frac{3x^2+3x+1}{2}$. Your answer is missing the denominator. Can you explain why the question received so many negative votes?

Comment: Ah, ok, since this is an inequality, $\frac{3x^2+3x+1}{2}\lessgtr 0$ is the same as $3x^2+3x+1\lessgtr 0$, since it's just a multiple by some constant. For example, I can divide both sides of my equation by 2, and the statement will still be true. As for negative votes, perhaps it's because it's not quite interesting as a puzzle, and more like standard math questions. Maybe you don't see this as standard question, but apparently many other people (me included actually, but I didn't downvote) see it as standard (meaning no new thinking process required).